# Extract Values stored in a certain pattern from a string in R and store in a data frame

Tags: r

I have a string doc which is read as a single string / factor variable in R. Glimpse below:

`this is a shirt here a="dhfaskdjfk" and this is the pair of jeans a="eruqiourmfmd". These are tees a="feriuwoeiru" and these are trousers a="eruawiorvnxmc"`

I want a data frame out of it that has (value in a=""):

```
dhfaskdjfk
eruqiourmfmd
feriuwoeiru
eruawiorvnxmc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `str_extract_all`

```
library(stringr)
v1 <- str_extract_all(str1, '(?<=a=")[^"]+')[[1]]
v1 
#[1] "dhfaskdjfk"    "eruqiourmfmd"  "feriuwoeiru"   "eruawiorvnxmc"

d1 <- data.frame(v1, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

#### data

```
str1 <- 'this is a shirt here a="dhfaskdjfk" and this is the pair of jeans a="eruqiourmfmd". These are tees a="feriuwoeiru" and these are trousers a="eruawiorvnxmc"'
```